# How to wirte String to c:out

Tags: jsp, jstl, cout

I have

```
String categoryDescription="something";
```

and when i write

```
<c:out value="${categoryDescription}" />
```

it's not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Scriptlets should be avoided. Completely avoided. So you should never have to display a local variable like this.

The JSP EL expression `${categoryDescription}` looks for an *attribute* (and not a local variable) named `categoryDescription`. It first looks for such an attribute in the page, then in the request, then in the session, then in the application (ServletContext).

So, you need to store the string as an attribute of one of these scopes to make it available to the JSP EL. For example, from your controller (implemented as a servlet for example):

```
request.setAttribute("categoryDescription", "something");
```